# Can't add XML file into mysql table

Tags: mysql, xml

I am trying to add an XML file into mysql database, *books* table. When creating fields for the *books* I used this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE books (id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
author varchar(255), 
title varchar(255), 
genre varchar(255),
price decimal, 
publish_date varchar(255), 
description text);
```

My XML file (books.xml) is stored in Documents. I'm trying to use this query:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/Documents/books.xml' INTO TABLE books;
```

What I get back:

```
File '/Documents/books.xml' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

**What I tried so far:**

- Not using LOCAL keyword
- `sudo cp` my books.xml file into mysql database directory and trying to add it from there
- X times checking my syntax to see if I made any errors
- Trying out different locations from which I called file
- Checking other questions like this asked

**EDIT** 
Found my problem. I had to move my book.xml file into VM's directory and it worked. Now new problem arised. It adds the xml file into table but the set is empty.

Comment: **EDIT** Found my problem. I had to move my book.xml file into VM's directory and it worked. Now new problem arised. It adds the xml file into table but the set is empty.

`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the original problem the solution was that my XML file was not in a VM's environment, so mysql couldn't reach it. I had to move `books.xml` to Vagrant's directory, public folder, then I was able to load it into table.

For the second problem (0 rows affected after import), I had to add `ROWS IDENTIFIED BY <book>` at the end of my query, this worked fine and it added all my book objects into the DB as I wanted. I hope this will help everyone who will face the same problem.